# Expected Value for a Sequential Poisson Random Variable

Tags: probability

### The set up:

A mouse nest contains $n$ female mice. In a particular year, the number of female offspring that each female mouse produces has the following pmf:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{\alpha}{x!} & x = 0, 1, 2, \ldots\\[8pt] 0 & \text{else} \end{cases}
$$
for some fixed $\alpha$. Assume the offspring are able to breed in the next year and that all mice behave independently. Let $Y_1$ be the total number of female offspring produced in one year from $n$ mice. Assume that no female mice die. Then after a single year, there are $Y_1 +n$ female rats which can each produce offspring. Let $Y_k$ denote the number of female mice produced in the $k^{th}$ year.

### The problem:

Inductively show that $E[Y_k] = 2^{k-1}n$.

### My approach

First, we note that $f(x)$ is a Poisson($\lambda$) distribution where $\alpha = 1/e$ and $\lambda = 1$. Since each mouse is independent, $Y_1$ is the sum of independent Poisson random variables. Hence $Y_1 \sim Pois(n)$. So the basis step of the induction proof is done, since $E[Y_1] = n$.

For induction step, I start by assuming $E[Y_k] = 2^{k-1}n$, then I want to show $E[Y_{k+1}] = 2^{k}n$.

Maybe there's a better way to go tackle this problem. I've chased it around and haven't been able to catch up with it. Any ideas?

Comment: Rats and mice are different species.  which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $E[Y_{k+1}] = E[E[Y_{k+1}\mid Y_k,Y_{k-1},\ldots,Y_1]]$.

Comment: I changed $[A|B]$ to $[A\mid B]$ (using \mid).  I think that's standard.